# For Every Representation of a Subgroup is there a Group such that the Group Representation is Irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, group-extensions

Let $H$ be a finite group, Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\rho$ a representation of $H$ on $V$. Is there, for any representation $\rho$ of $H$ on $V$, another finite group $G$, $H < G$, such that $\tau$ is a represenation of $G$ on $V$, $\tau(h) = \rho(h) \ \forall h \in H$, and $\tau$ is irreducible?

My intuition says this is false, but I have had no traction whatsoever in proving it.

Comment: I see people are downvoting and closing, presumably for lack of work presented, but I find the question interesting in itself - it's not a basic textbook problem, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @runway44 It is surely not true without extra assumptions, for example there are no restrictions on $\rho$ in the question statement. If $\rho$ were a trivial representation and $\dim V > 2$, then there does not exist any subgroup for which the restriction is irreducible.

Comment: @Joppy I don't understand your proposed counterexample: G is a supergroup, not a subgroup, of $H$.

Comment: BTW, if $V=\bigoplus n_iU_i$ as an $H$-rep, we can interpret $n_iU_i$ (a direct sum of $n_i$ copies of an irrep $U_i$) as $U_i\otimes\Bbb C^{n_i}$ and then put any $n_i$-dim rep of some $H_i$ on $\Bbb C^{n_i}$. Doing this for each $i$, we get a direct sum of *distinct* irreps of $H\times\prod H_i$. | @Joppy Read the question. | Also, as Stephen's answer indicates, you should use the word finite lest people post a response to a trivial version of the question.

Comment: I see that you've changed your question to specify that the groups involved should be *finite*. Since this makes my answer seem irrelevant, I'm going to delete it. (Perhaps you will understand that this is mildly annoying for me). For posterity: the answer to your original post was *yes*: simply take the group $G$ to be the free product of $H$ with $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ with the obvious action on $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The question for general groups has been answered in the positive.
If $H$ is a finite group and you insist that $G$ is also a finite group, however, then the answer is no, in general.

Let $H = 2.A_5 \times \mathbf{Z}/p \mathbf{Z}$ for any prime $p > 7$. (Here $2.A_5 = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{F}_5)$ is a non-trivial central extension of $A_5$.) The group $2.A_5$ has a faithful representation of dimension $2$, and $\mathbf{Z}/p \mathbf{Z}$ has a faithful representation of dimension $1$. Let $V$ be the direct sum of these representations, which is reducible of dimension $3$.
Then $V$ as a representation of $H$ is not the restriction of any irreducible
representation of a finite group $G$. We may assume that $G$ acts faithfully on $V$, since otherwise we
can replace $G$ by the image, which still contains $H$ because $H$ acts faithfully.
I claim that the action of $G$ on $V$ is  primitive,  that is, it is not induced from a  subgroup $P$ with $[G:P] > 1$.
Since $3 = \mathrm{dim}(V)$ is prime, $V$ would necessarily be induced from a character $\chi$ of an index $3$ subgroup $P$. But this would force $G$
to be solvable: it admits a map to $S_3$ (acting on the left cosets $G/P$), and the restriction of $V$ to the kernel $N$ is just a direct sum of characters, namely $\chi |_{N}$ and its conjugates by $G$. Since $N$ acts faithfully, this means that $N$ is abelian, and thus $G$ is solvable. Since $H$ is not solvable, this is impossible. On the other hand, there are only finitely many subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ which act primitively.
For $n = 3$, they have projective image one of six groups, the non-simple examples being $A_5$, $A_6$, and $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{F}_7)$.
(See [finite subgroups of PGL(3,C)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/finite-subgroups-of-pgl3-c))
Since the element of order $p$ in $H$ does not act diagonally on $V$, it acts non-trivially on the projective representation. For $p$ big enough ($p > 7$ in this case) this is a contradiction
with the possible primitive subgroups of $\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbf{C})$.

Comment: Why is $N$ abelian? (Also I would say the elt of ord $p$ acts diagonally, just not by a scalar.)

Comment: @runway44 The subgroup $P$ stabilizes a line whose images under $G$ give a direct sum decomposition of $V$; $N$ is the set of elements that stabilize all three of these lines, so that in the repreentation $V$ it is given by diagonal matrices and is therefore abelian.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks. I realized after posting my comment but forgot to update. Anyway this is a great answer and I'm glad the question stayed open.